# C# Web api does not open port on Kestrel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, .net-core

I extend my .NET Core 2.2 **console application with a api** endpoint.
This application runs **on a kestrel** (as service). The **port** should be **5003**.

The console application is doing its work. But I **cant reach the endpoint**.
When I call at Putty: *sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 5003*
than I get nothing in return. My two other apis I find when calling sudo netstat -tulpn

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State   PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29745/dotnet
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7681/dotnet
```

On localhost I can access the endpoint using swagger or straight on url:port/myApiEndpoint.

At the Program.cs WebHostBuilder I register Kestrel and the port:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
       .UseStartup<Startup>()
       .UseApplicationInsights()
       .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5003")
       .UseKestrel()
       .UseNLog();
```

And at the launchSettings.json I tell how to handle the application on kestrel:

```
{
"profiles": {
  "DataPicker.Cli": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "environmentVariables": {
      "Key": "Value",
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    },
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5003/"
  },
  "CZKestrel": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    },
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5003/"
    }
  }
}
```

**What I could try, what is missing that my application is opening the port 5003 on kestrel and I could reach my api endpoint?**